# How to send two generic parameters in Messenger.Default.Send<param1, param2>

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, messaging

I need to send asynchronously some data from one place to another.
For that I use GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.

If I have one parameter to send there is no problem.

Fe.

```
//Sends 
public void SendDriverToClient(Driver driver)
{
   Messenger.Default.Send<Driver>(driver, MessengerTokensServer.ReceiveDriver);
}

//Register
Messenger.Default.Register<Driver>(this, MessengerTokensServer.ReceiveDriver, ReceiveDriver);

//Receive
private void ReceiveDriver(Driver driver)
{
   //Instructions
}
```

The problem is when I have multiple parameters to send.

Fe.

```
public void SendLinesUpdatedInTOToClient(int toTempId, TransportOrder to)
{
        Messenger.Default.Send<int, TransportOrder>(*Here I should have to place toTempId & to*, MessengerTokensServer.GetUpdatedTransportOrder);
}
```

I already had my own solution but probably it's not the right way to do it. Current code is like this:

```
class ObjectHolder    
{
    public TransportOrder UpdatedTransportOrder { get; set; }
    public int TempId { get; set; }
} 

public void SendLinesUpdatedInTOToClient(int toTempId, TransportOrder to)
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<ObjectHolder>(new ObjectHolder{UpdatedTransportOrder = to, TempId = toTempId}, MessengerTokensServer.GetUpdatedTransportOrder);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I thinks it the right way to do it because you can't send 2 parameters in the same time. You need to create, like you did, a message object if you need to pass more data.

Comment: Thought so it was not possible but was not sure. I will use the Tuple class as Sheridan recommends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) page on MSDN. A `Tuple` is a generic holder of data... You can use it like this:

```
Tuple<int, TransportOrder> data = new Tuple<int, TransportOrder>(toTempId, to);
```

They are very useful 'containers' and can take up to 8 input parameters.

You can then access the values at the other end, like this:

```
int toTempId = data.Item1;
TransportOrder to = data.Item2;
```

Comment: I changed the code where I used ObjectHolder to Tuple. Thanks for the hint. Did not know there was a class like this.